# unescape returned value from filters

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i want to use filters to swap returned value into html checklist icon by doing like this

```
filters: {
        checkStatus: function(value){
            if(value > 0){
                return '<span class="bg-orange-400 text-highlight"><i class="icon-check"></i></span>'
            }else{
                return '<span class="bg-teal-300 text-highlight"><i class="icon-cross3"></i></span>'
            }
        }
    }
```

and in my table i just make it like this

```
<td>{{props.item.published | checkStatus}}</td>
```

but it instead returning icon or some html tags, it just returning escaped html. so how to make it return an unescaped value? i tried to use triple curly braces but not working.

or i do it wrong? i know that i can use v-if and v-else in html too, but this way it is more cleaner and i can reuse it for other value.

**update**

someone point out to use computed property and yes that is the first thing that come across my mind but i just can't use that... please take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934286/v-if-inside-template-props?noredirect=1#comment78911989_45934286) so my `props.item.published` is come from my child component inside v-for slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `v-html` and call the filter through `$options`

```
<td v-html="$options.filters.checkStatus(props.item.published)"></td>
```

But I would really suggest using a computed property or inline ternary expression on the bound class instead e.g.

With inline ternary:

```
<td>
    <span :class="[props.item.published > 0 ? 'bg-orange-400' : 'bg-teal-300']" class="text-highlight">
        <i :class="[props.item.published > 0 ? 'icon-check' : 'icon-cross3']"></i>
    </span>
</td>
```

With computed properties:

```
<td>
    <span :class="spanClass" class="text-highlight">
        <i :class="iconClass"></i>
    </span>
</td>
```

```
computed: {
    spanClass() {
        return this.props.item.published > 0 ? 'bg-orange-400' : 'bg-teal-300';
    },
    iconClass() {
        return this.props.item.published > 0 ? 'icon-check' : 'icon-cross3';
    },
}
```

Comment: okay well computed is the first method that come across my mind but the problem is props.item.published is a props that come from my child component and i can't access it using this.props.item.published... please see my updated post

Comment: @LaurensiusTony okay well did you try calling filter through $options?